# Datadog: how to get redis cpu usage metrics?

Tags: database, redis, datadog

Taking a look at [Redis metrics for Datadog](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/redisdb/?tab=host) , we can see that `redis.cpu.sys` refers to *System CPU consumed by the Redis server.* But this is metric for CPU usage time, not CPU usage.

How do we do if we want to create alerts based on the actual CPU usage?